# Sorting an array alphabetically before filtering and mapping it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm generating a drop down list with a React component.

I want to sort the array before I filter and map it out, but it keeps saying:

```
data.sort.filter is not a function
```

But I looked up arrays and javascript, and I do see a method called 'sort' so I'm not sure why it's not letting me sort it.

Here is my code:

```
const OptionList = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(
                'api/departments',
            );
            setData(result.data);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {data.sort.filter(item => item.groupById === 2).map((item, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={item.id} label={item.name} />
            ))}

            <optgroup label="Other"></optgroup>
            {data.sort.filter(item => item.groupById === 1).map((item, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={item.id} label={item.name} />
            ))}
        </>

    );
}
export default OptionList;
```

The data in 'data' is an array of objects that look like this:

```
{
  "id": 34,
  "name": "Massive Gaming Hillbilly Club",
  "groupById": 2
},
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Sort is a function. You are not using it correctly, ill create a demo for you so that you can clearly underatand it

Comment: That is not how you use [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort). Depending on what data is you can do something like this: `['a','b'].sort((a,b)=>a.localeCompare(b))` but you don't want to mutate data as it's state so copy before sorting: `[...data].sort((a,b)=>` on what property would like like to sort on?

Comment: @HMR Hi thank you, my data is an array of objects.  Each object has an id, name, and another id.  I want to sort alphabetically by the 'name' part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort by name property and I assume it's a string then you can do:

```
{[...data].sort((a,b)=>a.name.localeCompare(b.name)).filter
```

I am copying data first because sort will mutate it.

You can also sort it when you set the state:

```
setData(result.data.sort((a,b)=>a.name.localeCompare(b.name)));
```

Here I am mutating data because it came from axios and after setting state you don't use it anymore.

Comment: thank you, so this will protect state like you mentioned in another comment?  thanks

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Yes, you can sort a shallow copy `[...data]` and not mutate. But you can just sort it once when you set state, the `data` you sort there is what axios gave you and you can mutate that because that data goes out of scope in the next line.

Comment: but I use data.filter twice in my code to separate the option values into groups.  Will this still sort alphabetically for both? thanks

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell They would both sort by name so they're both the same right? Only the filter is different.

Comment: Hi thanks well the section of the dropdown lists is for normal role-playing and first person shooters.  "Other" is for card games, sports, etc...  But I want them to both be sorted within their respective groups.

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling the sort function.
You probably meant something like:

`data.sort().filter( ..... )`

You'll also have to pass a function to compare items to the sort function to tell it how to sort.

As @HMR mentioned, sort() mutates data in this case, which you probably don't want at this place in your code. You could make a copy, or do the sorting elsewhere.

Comment: sort mutates and data is state so you're now mutating state. Also items in data seem to be objects so that won't work.

Comment: @HMR, you're right about the mutating of data here. good point. It's a another problem with the code that needs to be tackled by SkyeBoniwell.

Comment: Thanks Wouter and @HMR.  I just want to sort it for the dropdowns.  Should I sort inside my method where I make the api call?  Thanks

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell If the order the data came from the api has some importance then sort it when you render it (make a copy with [...data] to not mutate). If the order is of no importance then better sort it when you set the state, no copy is needed here because at that moment you're not mutating state.

Answer (score 1):

Sort is a function, so you need to call it

```
data.sort().filter(...)
```

Comment: sort mutates and items in data are not strings.